# Stored Procedure insert only one record from the Temporary Table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been writing this stored procedure, and I am kind of new to Stored Procedures. I have been trying to put the insert into loops, but the logic is not right.

Basically the stored procedure below only inserts the last row into the table. 
However when I print out the temporary table, it shows all the data correctly, but somehow the insert/update not working correctly

Below is the script of the stored procedure. Can anyone tell, what did I miss here?

```
--exec [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable] @templateID=1,@parameterList='0:C:Test:True:0,0:B:TEST2:False:0,0:A-b/c*a::False:0',
--@EmployeeNo = 'test'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable]
(     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@templateID nvarchar(max),
@parameterList nvarchar(max),
@EmployeeNo nvarchar(16)
)     
AS
BEGIN


Declare @ErrorNo integer = '',

@ErrorMessage nvarchar(max) = '',
@SPName nvarchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @paramID nvarchar(MAX),@formula nvarchar(MAX), @property nvarchar(MAX),@samplesRequired nvarchar(MAX),@tUnitOfMeasures_id int,
@Pos int,@strSampleData nvarchar(MAX),@IntCounter int,@test int

      DECLARE @tmpParameterParam table
            (
                paramID nvarchar(MAX),
                  formula nvarchar(MAX),
                  property nvarchar(MAX),
                  samplesRequired nvarchar(MAX),
                  tUnitOfMeasures_id int

                  )


      SET @parameterList = LTRIM(RTRIM (@parameterList))+ ','
      SET @Pos = CHARINDEX (',', @parameterList,1)
      --SET @IntCounter = 1
            IF REPLACE(@parameterList, ',' , '') <> ''
                  begin 
                        WHILE @Pos > 0
                        BEGIN 
                              SET @strSampleData = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@parameterList, @Pos -1)))
                              IF @strSampleData  <> ''

                              BEGIN 

                                    set @paramID = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    --Remove the substring and move the string to the next token(column)
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@paramID)+2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    set @formula = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    --Remove the substring and move the string to the next token(column)
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@formula)+2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    --update tSpecScaleValidation set LastTriggeredTime=getdate() where id= @tSpecScaleValidation_id

                                    set @property = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@property)+2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    set @samplesRequired = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@samplesRequired)+4, LEN(@strSampleData))         


                                    set @tUnitOfMeasures_id = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                     --to get the last token from the string(column)
                                    set @tUnitOfMeasures_id = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@tUnitOfMeasures_id)+1, LEN(@strSampleData))   



                                    insert into @tmpParameterParam
                                    --select @IntCounter,@strSampleData
                                    select  @paramID,@formula,@property,@samplesRequired,@tUnitOfMeasures_id


                              END
                              SET @parameterList = RIGHT(@parameterList, LEN (@parameterList) - @Pos)
                              set @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @parameterList,1)
                              SET @IntCounter = @IntCounter + 1
                        END
                  END 

                  begin transaction t1


                  begin try
                        declare @setno int
                        select * from @tmpParameterParam
                        --begin 
                            if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tTemplate_Calculation where id = @paramID)
                                update tTemplate_Calculation 
                                set formula=@formula,
                                property = @property , 
                                samplesRequired=@samplesRequired, 
                                tUnitOfMeasures_id=@tUnitOfMeasures_id
                                where id = @paramID
                            else
                                insert into tTemplate_Calculation 
                                select @templateID,@formula,@property,@samplesRequired,@tUnitOfMeasures_id,@EmployeeNo,getdate()
                                FROM @tmpParameterParam 

                        --end
                        commit transaction t1

                  end try

      Begin Catch 
            Select 
                  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                  @SPName = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
                  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();

            rollback transaction t1

            select @ErrorMessage
      End Catch

END
```

Comment: I was trying to insert and update the records based on the temporary table. but it just insert the last row

Comment: also, I have a checking, if the paramID is 0, it should insert, else, update the table

Comment: This fails when the table is empty with Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'False??' to data type bit and nothing is inserted when execute with exec [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable] @templateID=1,@parameterList='0:C:Test:True:0,0:B:TEST2:Fals‌​e:0,0:A-b/c*a::False‌​:0', @EmployeeNo = 'test' and 3 rows shown are debug select statements in procedure.

Comment: The insert statement is incorrect the fields coming from the table variable should not be preceeded by @. You might want to change the samplesrequired to something other than bit or change the parameters from true and false to 1 or 0. I would add some validation logic to the procedure and tighten up on the table definitions to include allowed values. The update phase may cause problems since it will only update on the last @paramid found in your input string is this what you really want (and it will never find where paramid = 0 because the identity column always starts from 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following. I have executed it successfully in my Sql server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable]
(
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @templateID NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @parameterList NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @EmployeeNo NVARCHAR(16)
)
AS 
BEGIN


    DECLARE @ErrorNo INTEGER,
        @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SPName NVARCHAR(MAX) 

    DECLARE @paramID NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @formula NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @property NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @samplesRequired NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @tUnitOfMeasures_id INT,
        @Pos INT,
        @strSampleData NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @IntCounter INT,
        @test INT

    DECLARE @tmpParameterParam TABLE
(
  paramID NVARCHAR(MAX),
  formula NVARCHAR(MAX),
  property NVARCHAR(MAX),
  samplesRequired NVARCHAR(MAX),
  tUnitOfMeasures_id INT
)


    SET @parameterList = LTRIM(RTRIM(@parameterList)) + ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @parameterList, 1)
      --SET @IntCounter = 1
    IF REPLACE(@parameterList, ',', '') <> '' 
        BEGIN 
            WHILE @Pos > 0 
                BEGIN 
                    SET @strSampleData = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@parameterList, @Pos - 1)))
                    IF @strSampleData <> '' 
                        BEGIN 

                            SET @paramID = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @strSampleData, 0)) 
                                    --Remove the substring and move the string to the next token(column)
                            SET @strSampleData = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, LEN(@paramID) + 2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                            SET @formula = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @strSampleData, 0)) 
                                    --Remove the substring and move the string to the next token(column)
                            SET @strSampleData = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, LEN(@formula) + 2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    --update tSpecScaleValidation set LastTriggeredTime=getdate() where id= @tSpecScaleValidation_id

                            SET @property = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @strSampleData, 0)) 
                            SET @strSampleData = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, LEN(@property) + 2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                            SET @samplesRequired = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @strSampleData, 0)) 
                            SET @strSampleData = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, LEN(@samplesRequired) + 4, LEN(@strSampleData))         


                            SET @tUnitOfMeasures_id = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @strSampleData, 0)) 
                                     --to get the last token from the string(column)
                            SET @tUnitOfMeasures_id = SUBSTRING(@strSampleData, LEN(@tUnitOfMeasures_id) + 1, LEN(@strSampleData))   



                            INSERT  INTO @tmpParameterParam
                                    --select @IntCounter,@strSampleData
                                    SELECT  @paramID, @formula, @property, @samplesRequired, @tUnitOfMeasures_id


                        END
                    SET @parameterList = RIGHT(@parameterList, LEN(@parameterList) - @Pos)
                    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @parameterList, 1)
                    SET @IntCounter = @IntCounter + 1
                END
        END 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION t1


    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @setno INT
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @tmpParameterParam
                        --begin 
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    tTemplate_Calculation
                    WHERE   id = @paramID ) 
            UPDATE  tTemplate_Calculation
            SET     formula = @formula, property = @property, samplesRequired = @samplesRequired, tUnitOfMeasures_id = @tUnitOfMeasures_id
            WHERE   id = @paramID
        ELSE 
            INSERT  INTO tTemplate_Calculation
                    SELECT  @templateID, @formula, @property, @samplesRequired, @tUnitOfMeasures_id, @EmployeeNo, GETDATE()
                    FROM    @tmpParameterParam 

                        --end
        COMMIT TRANSACTION t1

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
        SELECT  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @SPName = ERROR_PROCEDURE(), @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() ;

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1

        SELECT  @ErrorMessage


    END CATCH

END
```

Comment: thanks @Rajan, however it still insert the last row from the temporary table 3 times.

Comment: can you pl give me a sql to generate table "tTemplate_Calculation" and give me a parameter list to execute SP

Comment: GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tTemplate_Calculation]    Script Date: 9/13/2017 2:43:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tTemplate_Calculation](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [tTemplate_id] [int] NULL,
 [formula] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [property] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [samplesRequired] [bit] NULL,
 [tUnitOfMeasures_id] [int] NULL,
 [employeeNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [dateTimeStamps] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: above is the sql table , and this is what I have been using exec [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable] @templateID=1,@parameterList='0:C:Test:True:0,0:B:TEST2:False:0,0:A-b/c*a::False:0',
@EmployeeNo = 'test'

Comment: Here I am getting error so, print all the values that you set in variables to get details what happens when you are using substring method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are that far away. My understanding is that you want to have 1 row per paramid in tTemplate_Calculation so I would change the table definition 
so that paramid is unique but not an identity type.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tTemplate_Calculation]( 
[id] [int] unique, --IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[tTemplate_id] [int] NULL, 
[formula] [nvarchar](10) NULL, 
[property] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
[samplesRequired] [bit] NULL, 
[tUnitOfMeasures_id] [int] NULL, 
[employeeNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
[dateTimeStamps] [datetime] NULL )
```

,amend the sp to include an identity column in the table variable and when you come to the update/insert phase use @i and @j variables to create a loop using offset and fetch passing data from the table variable back to the declared variables

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable]
(     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@templateID nvarchar(max),@parameterList nvarchar(max),@EmployeeNo nvarchar(16))     
AS
BEGIN
Declare @ErrorNo integer = '',
@ErrorMessage nvarchar(max) = '',
@SPName nvarchar(max) = '',
@i int ,
@j int
DECLARE @paramID nvarchar(MAX),@formula nvarchar(MAX), @property nvarchar(MAX),@samplesRequired nvarchar(MAX),@tUnitOfMeasures_id int,
@Pos int,@strSampleData nvarchar(MAX),@IntCounter int,@test int
DECLARE @tmpParameterParam table (id int identity , paramID nvarchar(MAX), formula nvarchar(MAX), property nvarchar(MAX), samplesRequired nvarchar(MAX),tUnitOfMeasures_id int)
set @i = 0
set @j = 0
      SET @parameterList = LTRIM(RTRIM (@parameterList))+ ','
      SET @Pos = CHARINDEX (',', @parameterList,1)
      --SET @IntCounter = 1
            IF REPLACE(@parameterList, ',' , '') <> ''
                  begin 
                        WHILE @Pos > 0
                        BEGIN 
                              SET @strSampleData = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@parameterList, @Pos -1)))
                              IF @strSampleData  <> ''

                              BEGIN 

                                    set @paramID = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    --Remove the substring and move the string to the next token(column)
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@paramID)+2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    set @formula = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    --Remove the substring and move the string to the next token(column)
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@formula)+2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    --update tSpecScaleValidation set LastTriggeredTime=getdate() where id= @tSpecScaleValidation_id

                                    set @property = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@property)+2, LEN(@strSampleData))

                                    set @samplesRequired = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                    set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@samplesRequired)+4, LEN(@strSampleData))         

                                    set @tUnitOfMeasures_id = substring(@strSampleData,0, CHARINDEX(':',@strSampleData,0)) 
                                     --to get the last token from the string(column)
                                    set @tUnitOfMeasures_id = substring(@strSampleData, LEN(@tUnitOfMeasures_id)+1, LEN(@strSampleData))   

                                    insert into @tmpParameterParam
                                    --select @IntCounter,@strSampleData
                                    select  @paramID,@formula,@property,@samplesRequired,@tUnitOfMeasures_id

                              END
                              SET @parameterList = RIGHT(@parameterList, LEN (@parameterList) - @Pos)
                              set @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @parameterList,1)
                              SET @IntCounter = @IntCounter + 1
                              set @i = @i + 1
                        END
                  END 
                  select @i as intcounter
                  begin transaction t1
                  begin try
                        declare @setno int

                        while @j < @i 
                         begin 
                              select @paramID = t.paramID ,
                                    @formula = t.formula,
                                    @property = t.property,
                                    @samplesRequired = t.samplesRequired,
                                    @tUnitOfMeasures_id = t.tUnitOfMeasures_id
                              from @tmpParameterParam t 
                               order by t.id offset @i rows fetch next 1 rows only

                            if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tTemplate_Calculation where id = @paramid)
                                begin 
                                select 'updating' , @i, @j
                                update tTemplate_Calculation 
                                set formula= @formula,
                                property = @property , 
                                samplesRequired=@samplesRequired, 
                                tUnitOfMeasures_id=@tUnitOfMeasures_id

                                end
                            else
                                begin
                                select 'inserting' , @i, @j
                                insert into tTemplate_Calculation 
                                (   [id],
                                    [tTemplate_id] , 
                                    [formula] , 
                                    [property], 
                                    [samplesRequired], 
                                    [tUnitOfMeasures_id] , 
                                    [employeeNo] , 
                                    [dateTimeStamps])

                                select @paramid, @templateID,@formula,@property,@samplesRequired,@tUnitOfMeasures_id,@EmployeeNo,getdate()
                                end 
                            set @j =@j + 1
                         end
                        commit transaction t1
                  end try
      Begin Catch 
            Select 
                  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                  @SPName = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
                  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
            rollback transaction t1
            select @ErrorMessage
      End Catch

END
```

When the sp is called

```
set nocount on
truncate table tTemplate_Calculation

exec [dbo].[spAddIntoTemplateCalculationsTable] @templateID=1,@parameterList='0:C:Test:0:0,0:B:TEST2:1:0,0:A-b/c*a::0:0', @EmployeeNo = 'test'
select * from tTemplate_Calculation
```

This is the result

```
intcounter
-----------
3


--------- ----------- -----------
inserting 3           0


-------- ----------- -----------
updating 3           1


-------- ----------- -----------
updating 3           2

id          tTemplate_id formula    property                                           samplesRequired tUnitOfMeasures_id employeeNo                                         dateTimeStamps
----------- ------------ ---------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------ -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------
0           1            A-b/c*a                                                       0               0                  test                                               2017-09-13 13:05:12.310
```